# how to handle no record found in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, no-data

I have a procedure with select statement below:

```
SELECT TYPE 
INTO v_type
FROM timeperiodtype
WHERE projectid = 15;
```

I have no record with projectid =15. So no record will retrieve. Is there any way I can get null instead of nothing from this query if I dont have record for 15.

I have already tried ifnull, nullif and I can use declare handler but  I am using it with cursor. Is it possible to use the same declare handler for this query if yes then please explain with some example.

Comment: Can you combine it with COUNT?

Comment: trick worked :) thank you @Shomz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly initialize `v_type` with `NULL` prior to executing `SELECT INTO`

```
SET v_type = NULL;
SELECT TYPE 
  INTO v_type
  FROM timeperiodtype
 WHERE projectid = 15;
```

or just use `SET` statement

```
SET v_type = 
(
  SELECT TYPE 
    FROM timeperiodtype
   WHERE projectid = 15;
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3926a/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

First initialize v_type with any initial value  OR  use 'AS' instead of 'INTO' in the below query

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(TYPE) > 0, TYPE, NULL) 
INTO v_type
FROM timeperiodtype
WHERE projectid = 15;
```